# Sass - use value from default css if custom property is null

Tags: css, sass

im creating a vue app.
At the moment I have a light.scss and a dark.scss and decide in the build process which one I use.
But I want to toggle the dark mode directly in my app.
Im using a css theme and until now I could write:

light.scss

```
$header-bar-color: null;
```

dark.scss

```
$header-bar-color: black;
```

The light variant took the default value from my css theme.

Now I want to use only one main.scss with custom properties.
Therefore I have a light.scss with:

```
--header-bar-color: null
```

and a dark.scss with:

```
--header-bar-color: black
```

and in my main.scss I write:

```
$header-bar-color: var(--header-bar-color)
```

My Problem is that the null value from the light theme don't fallback to my default css theme. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/a-dry-approach-to-color-themes-in-css/ check this post, this a nice approcah on how to easily do this.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but how does this help me?
I need something like $header-bar-color: var(--header-bar-color, null) and if its null it should use the default from the css. I can't change anything in the css, I want to ignore the scss if no value is set.

Comment: You can't ignore it, since that's not how CSS works. You can restructure your project to use the described approach. Or use a completely different approach... like this https://css-tricks.com/dark-modes-with-css/

Comment: But I can ignore it with: $header-bar-color: null.

Comment: That's because it's a variable from SASS, not CSS. These are two different things. If you want to use custom property from CSS you have to use one of the approaches I linked you (Or find an even different one)

Comment: Okay thanks!
Is there a way with only scss?
So like before when I used one of the 2 scss files in the build  process. Can I load load scss files and decide in app which one I use?

Comment: That's explained in the second link I commented. Create two different css files, one for dark and one for not dark. That's totally doable with SCSS. in the end the browser only cares about the CSS it get's anyhow.

Comment: I want to toggle dark/light mode in app with 2 different css files. I can't see where the second link describes this..

Comment: They show it in one CSS file, but you can of course split it also up in two files. I think you have a wrong understanding how CSS in combination with dark mode works. You can't just load only one CSS file depending on the mode you have activated. You would need link 1 for a solution that comes close to what you want.